# Storing arraylist of arraylists in SQLite

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I'm new to Android development, and I'm developing a memo/note-taking app that allows the user to include hashtags and then browse saved notes by said hashtags.

I already have a note app working that saves just the notes in an SQLite database, but I plan to store the hashtags by including an arraylist of hashtags within each of my note objects (which are already stored in an arraylist)...

My question is, how would I go about storing these arraylists of arraylists (note arraylists of hashtag arraylists) into an SQLite database?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You may want to try some question with some actual code that you might have tried, but did not work. Asking for opinions and guidance is not the scope of stackoverflow

Comment: Also, have a look to our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a sql table for notes, you should create another table to store hashtags. You can link every hashtag to it's note by reserving a column to store the note id which hashtag belongs. Structure should be basically something like this:

Note table:

```
note_id | note
```

Hashtags table:

```
hashtag_id | hashtag | note_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple technique : Just store all your hashtags as a single string.

For example, say a note has 4 hashtags - `#study, #homework, #school, #math`

So, you just store them as  a single string like:

```
String hastags="study#homework#school#math"
```

Now store this string in sqlite databse as the `hastag` column for every note object.

Java allows you to easily parse strings, so when you retrieve a note, you can gets it's `hashtag` column and separate it into a string array  (containing one string element for each hashtag) based on a delimiting character ("#" in this case) like so:

```
String hastags[]= hashtagStringFromDB.split("#");
```

Now, you have all your hashtags for that note object in a single string array which you can go through easily using `hashtag[0], hashtag[1]...etc`

**Another option** would be to create another `hashtags` table. Every hashtag goes into this table with a unique identifier (foreign key) to link it to a note in the `notes` table. So you can query this table with the `note_id` of a particular note and it will return all the hashtags belonging to that note.